# Sybase SQL request via VB-Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, sybase

I'd like to make a SQL request via a VBScript called by a CMD.
The Database is a Sybase Server and this is the problem, I can't find
any documentation about this, only MS SQL and stuff like this.

But it doesn't have to be a complex way like this, if somebody knows a small
tool that will output the request when it is executed I would be happy too.

But The main objective is, to output the requested datas as the programm (or script)
is executed.

**UPDATE**

I found something, that might be helpful

```
Dim OdbcDSN
Dim connect, sql, resultSet

OdbcDSN = "******;UID=*******;PWD=*****"
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connect.Open OdbcDSN

sql="SELECT * FROM **********..********** WHERE ******* = 1 AND Name = %given parameter%"

resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing

WScript.Quit(0)
```

Additonal Note: the batch (or whatever) will be executed by a a telefon client which will call the batch (or program) with a paramater, the name, of the person which is calling.
so if i can build the parameter into the query, that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `isql` utility?

Comment: Yes I'm on it right now, but I can't get it to execute the querys given by the cmd.

Comment: If the query you wish to execute is put in a file, you can pass that in as an Input File and isql will execute it.  You can also capture the output if you want to an output file or just have it return to the default output of your session.

Comment: I also thought about that, but the problem is, if i use an input file, I can't use the parameters of the telefon client which calls the program.

Comment: You can use VB to create the sql input file, then execute it via isql.  I frequently do this in *nix shells, and it works.

Comment: Ok, I found my solution: I created the Input-File via a Batch-Script. and than I started ISQL From the Batch, using the Input File. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same task and it looks like you just cant connect using standard ADODB.Connection. I made some research and found that you should use iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere lib and its own SybaseConnector.Connector to connect to Sybase. 
Instead of using batch to call vb vbscript file you can make your own COM object with SybaseConnector, register it to your system and create new object or make executable that takes sonnection string and query. I can share source with you.

Set up Sybase IQ 15.4 dev edition, then create project in Visual Studio and make reference to .NET component iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.

Then use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace SybaseConnector
{
    public class Connector
    {
        private SAConnection                _myConnection { get; set; }
        private SADataReader                _data { get; set; }
        private SACommand                   _comm { get; set; }
        private SAConnectionStringBuilder   _conStr { get; set; }
        public  bool                        isDebug { get; set; }

        public Connector(string UserID, string Password, string CommLinks, string ServerName, string command)
        {
            _conStr = new SAConnectionStringBuilder();

           // dynamic
            _conStr.UserID               = UserID;       //"dba";
            _conStr.Password             = Password;     //"sql";
            _conStr.CommLinks            = CommLinks;    //@"TCPIP{IP=servername;ServerPort=2638}";
            _conStr.ServerName           = ServerName;   //"northwind";

            // static
            _conStr.Compress             = "NO";
            _conStr.DisableMultiRowFetch = "NO";
            _conStr.Encryption           = "NONE";
            _conStr.Integrated           = "NO";

            this.Connect();
            this.ExecuteCommand(command);
            this.WriteResult();
        }

        public  void Connect()
        {
            _myConnection = new SAConnection();
            _myConnection.StateChange += new StateChangeEventHandler(ConnectionControl);

            if (_conStr.ToString() != String.Empty) 
            {
                try
                {
                    _myConnection.ConnectionString = _conStr.ToString();
                    _myConnection.Open();

                }
                catch(Exception e) 
                {
                    if ((int)_myConnection.State == 0)
                    {
                        _myConnection.Dispose();
                        WriteDebug("Exception data:\n"    + e.Data + "\n" +
                                   "Exception message:\n" + e.Message + "\n" + 
                                   "Inner exception:\n"   + e.InnerException + "\n" + 
                                   "StackTrace:\n"        + e.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public  void ExecuteCommand(string com, int timeout = 600)
        {
            if ((int)_myConnection.State != 0)
            {
                _comm                = new SACommand();
                _comm.CommandText    = com;
                _comm.CommandTimeout = timeout;
                _comm.Connection     = _myConnection;

                try
                {
                    _data = _comm.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    WriteDebug("Exception data:\n"    + e.Data           + "\n" +
                               "Exception message:\n" + e.Message        + "\n" +
                               "Inner exception:\n"   + e.InnerException + "\n" +
                               "StackTrace:\n"        + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                WriteDebug("Exception occured:\n" +
                           "Connection has been closed before the command has been executed.");
            }
        }

        private void ConnectionControl(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteDebug(sender.GetType().ToString() + ": Connection state changed to " + e.CurrentState.ToString());
        }

        public  void SetMaxReconnectCount(int count)
        {
            _reconnectCounter = count;
        }

        public  void Dispose()
        {
            _comm.Dispose();
            _data.Dispose();            
            _myConnection.Close();
            _myConnection.Dispose();
        }

        private void WriteResult()
        {
            var output = new StringBuilder();

            int count = _data.FieldCount;
            // аппенд в строку и вывод в ивент одним объектом
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (i == count - 1)
                {
                    output.Append(_data.GetName(i) + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Append(_data.GetName(i) + "\t");
                }
            }
            while (_data.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == count - 1)
                    {
                        output.Append(_data.GetValue(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Append(_data.GetValue(i) + "\t");
                    }
                }
            }

            WriteDebug(output.ToString());
        }

        private void WriteDebug(string str, EventLogEntryType type = EventLogEntryType.Information)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            appLog.Source = "SQL SybaseConnector";
            appLog.WriteEntry(str, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

set [ComVisible(true)] flag if you gonna use it as COM object.
Compile project and register your dll with command

```
>regasm myTest.dll
```

then with your vbscript code

```
Dim obj
Set obj = CreateObject("SybaseConnector.Connector")
Call obj.Connector("user","password","TCPIP{IP=host;ServerPort=2638}","northwind",command)
```